# Switch from mysql_connect to PDO: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I had code that used mysql_connect which I understand is now deprecated to I switched to the following code (I'm working locally):

```
<?php

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$DBusername = 'admin';

/*** mysql password ***/
$DBpassword = '';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mysql", $DBusername, $DBpassword);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    echo 'Connected to database';
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

But this now means that a function of mine breaks:

```
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Because, following the script back, the connection is not working. There is something up with my PDO connection script but I do not understand what I have done wrong. The details are correct for logging into phpMyAdmin on localhost.

```
function user_exists($username){
        $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        $result = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if($result == 1){
            // username does already exist
            return true;
        }else{
            // username doesn't exist in the database
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: PDO has its own method of checking row counts. For instance, when you execute a flat query, it returns the number of results. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php

Comment: @Rottingham is there something other than PDO I can use that will work with my previous functions? This is my first piece of code using PHP and I honestly don't know what I've done wrong or where to go.

Comment: PDO + `mysql_*` functions = Not a good mix. [`Read up on PDO`](http://php.net/pdo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDO is entirely independent from the `mysql` extension, you will have to update your function calls as well. `mysql_query` for example should be a combination of [`prepare`](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [`execute`](https://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

As a note: Please please use Prepared Statements, your example query is completely insecure.

As an example was requested:

```
// initialize PDO
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mysql", $DBusername, $DBpassword);

// Prepare a query
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
        FROM   users
        WHERE  username = ?
        LIMIT  1";
$statement = $dbh->prepare($sql);

// execute the query
$statement->execute(array($username));

// retrieve the first row
$row = $statement->fetch();

if ($row['count']) echo 'The user exists';
else echo 'The user does not exist';
```

Comment: What do I need to update to the functions to make it work? I don't understand the error.

Comment: @Francesca You have to change **all of them**, read the manual :)

Comment: And in what way? Can you offer what needs to be changed? What's wrong with them? Any information would be greatly appreciated. I have never worked with PHP or databases before. This was working with mysql_connect. Is there a major issue with continuing to use that? Because it works and this doesn't.

Comment: @Francesca I just added an example. And: The `mysql` extension should no longer be used and may be removed without any further warning in the future.

Comment: @Francesca To find out more about my example and what's possible with PDO read the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php